# has uitabbarcontroller changed in xcode 4

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode4

I recently upgraded to xcode 4.  My application utilizes tabbarcontroller.  In old xcode 3.x, you were able to change the tabs to different types per this screenshot:

[image]

From what I gather in researching this issue, xcode 4 no longer offers this functionality.  Am I missing something?  From what I researched we are now suppose to delete/add tabs then change attributes to get the desired effect.  So, to that end in xcode 4, I've added a new tab item and made the class a UINavigationController fully expecting the ability to toggle the "Shows Navigation Bar" with a checkbox.  But, the "Navigation Controller" grouping never appears.  What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised at first too and I was about to ask the same question. But, when you open the Object Library, in the bottom you can see a big star, "Tab Bar Item". Just drag that to the tab bar and you will notice a new item added to the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1):

Weird but works!
Just drag drop View Controller onto tabs!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I played with xcode 4 a little bit more and discovered you can drag Navigation Controller from library onto your UITabBarController and it will create your tab item for you and set it up as a NavigationController.  Pretty cool.  Hopefully this will help others.