# xcode 4 cannot find Tab Bar Controller Attributes

Tags: iphone, xcode4, tabbar

I am reading this [article](http://www.forwardecho.com/2008/11/creating-navigation-control-inside-tab.html) but in xcode 4 I cannot find the tab bar controller attributes.
The problem is in Step 6 where is this list???
Any ideas how I can access this list?
Or how I can make this step with xcode 4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301559/has-uitabbarcontroller-changed-in-xcode-4 found this solution but is it true? xcode does not support this list any more?

Answer (score 1):

> stackoverflow.com/questions/5301559/… found this solution but is it true? xcode does not support this list any more? – auslander yesterday

This is true.  Drag the Navigation Controller over the tab bar and wait for it to show the insertion mouse icon thingy.  You'll have to redo all your tabs if you are opening a xcode 3 project.

Ken